# Add API KEY to a Get request for Alexa Skill

Tags: node.js, json, get, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Im trying to add the API key to my Get request below? I have an example without the API key working below.

This is my Node.js code that is supposed to parse the JSON.

```
{ await getRemoteData(''https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'b54bcf4d-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c'
  }')

      .then((response) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(response);
        outputSpeech = `This is the name ${data[2].name} man look at that on a saturday morning.`;
      }
```

See JSON format for the above GET request below. 
This is the API URL but you need an API key to access it.

### https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest

```
JS eval
{
"0":{
"type":"coin",
"logoFile":"logos\/1.png",
"name":"Bitcoin",
"symbol":"BTC",
"price":5336.7412403400003313436172902584075927734375,
"marketcap":94232174265.99346923828125,
"volume":12689683492.3271999359130859375,
"rank":1,
"change":{
"hour":-0.0089407500000000007800426971016349853016436100006103515625,
"day":-0.139828000000000007840839089112705551087856292724609375,
"week":5.0347799999999995890220816363580524921417236328125
}
},
"1":{
"type":"coin",
"logoFile":"logos\/1027.png",
"name":"Ethereum",
"symbol":"ETH",
"price":172.80222112600000627935514785349369049072265625,
"marketcap":18273315192.039081573486328125,
"volume":5874660289.064609527587890625,
"rank":2,
"change":{
"hour":-0.11684999999999999553690344100687070749700069427490234375,
"day":-1.2512700000000001043787278831587173044681549072265625,
"week":5.626129999999999853343979339115321636199951171875
}
},
```

### This is a  working example of me parsing a JSON without an API key that works fine with a similarly formatted JSON.

```
 await getRemoteData('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(response);
        outputSpeech = `This is the name ${data[2].name} man look at that on a saturday morning.`;
      })
```

This is the API LINK below.

### https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "5260.8494713", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "13764287489.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "92951055841.0", 
        "available_supply": "17668450.0", 
        "total_supply": "17668450.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.14", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-0.28", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-1.42", 
        "last_updated": "1556377650"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ethereum", 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "rank": "2", 
        "price_usd": "156.835413228", 
        "price_btc": "0.02983922", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "6040899613.44", 
        "market_cap_usd": "16598483757.0", 
        "available_supply": "105833774.0", 
        "total_supply": "105833774.0", 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.45", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.04", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-9.81", 
        "last_updated": "1556377642"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ripple", 
        "name": "XRP", 
        "symbol": "XRP", 
        "rank": "3", 
        "price_usd": "0.2965559184", 
        "price_btc": "0.00005642", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "890277280.659", 
        "market_cap_usd": "12456821485.0", 
        "available_supply": "42004966728.0", 
        "total_supply": "99991643723.0", 
        "max_supply": "100000000000", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.21", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.8", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-10.2", 
        "last_updated": "1556377622"
    },
```